# Enquire.js interval detecting issue

Tags: javascript, enquire.js

I m currently using enquire.js to identify my media queries which are:

```
breakpoints[extra_large_devices] = only screen and (min-width: 1098px);
breakpoints[large_devices] = (min-width: 992px);
breakpoints[medium_devices] = (min-width: 768px);
breakpoints[small_devices] = (min-width: 544px)
breakpoints[extra_small_devices] = (min-width: 0px);
```

I need my js to fire for medium_devices so I worte:

```
Drupal.Breakpoints.register('medium_devices', {
  match: function() {
     console.log("match");
  },
  unmatch: function() {
     console.log("unmatch");
  },
});
```

So from 0 to 767 I get unmatched.
From 768 on I get matched. The problem is I want the unmatch to be firing at 992px too. So basically I need my script to work from 768 to 991 so rather than macth I need to identify the "active" media query.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks